# Replicating iA Writer's focus mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to dim everything except the current line/paragraph of text in a textarea?

The textarea is being used by SimpleMDE

link to [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/navanchauhan/pen/mvbxPo)

javascript

```
new SimpleMDE({
        element: document.getElementById("writer"),
        status: false,
        toolbar: false,
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="writingArea">
<textarea id="writer" class="textEditor"># This one is bare
You can also choose to hide the statusbar and/or toolbar for a simple and clean appearance. This one also checks for misspelled words as you type!</textarea>
</div>
```

I couldn't find any guide/how-to on the internet, so I have no clue how to do it. Else, I wouldn't have asked a low-effort question